# JFormDesigner missing designer file

Tags: java, user-interface, reverse-engineering, wysiwyg, jform-designer

I downloaded a project that the .java gui files say were generated using JFormDesigner but the jfd files are missing so it wont open the designer. I cant seem to find a java to jfd converter in the plugin or online. Is it possible to get the GUI designer back from .java files and if so how?

Comment: Where have you imported the code. In eclipse, NetBeans...